# PDFNet pdftron library throws "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" when use create() in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, pdftron, pdfnet

Please provide the solution as soon as possible, why pdftron.PDF.Image.Create(doc,bitmap,JBIG2_hint) gives exception "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow", but on the other hand if I try another overload function of Create(), then it works fine.

I am using this to Convert Image to PDF.

---

```
    private PDFDoc ConvertToPDF(System.Drawing.Image SourceImage)
    {
        string currentCulture = GetApplicationParameter("DataCenterCulture");
        if (currentCulture == "en-US")
        {
            PDFNet.Initialize("some value already passed correctly");
        }
        else
        {
            PDFNet.Initialize("some value already passed correctly");
        }

        string path = GetApplicationParameter("some_PDF_Path");
        bool found = PDFNet.SetResourcesPath(path);

        PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc();
        ElementBuilder f = new ElementBuilder();    // Used to build new Element objects
        ElementWriter writer = new ElementWriter(); // Used to write Elements to the page   
        Element element = null;
        // Use JBIG2 Encoding
        ObjSet hint_set = new ObjSet();
        pdftron.SDF.Obj JBIG2_hint = hint_set.CreateArray();
        JBIG2_hint.PushBack(hint_set.CreateName("g4"));
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GetPageCount(SourceImage); i++)
            {
                SourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                SourceImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                ms.Seek(0, 0);
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
                bitmap.SetResolution(200f, 200f);
                Page page = doc.PageCreate(); // Start a new page 
                writer.Begin(page); // Begin writing to this page
                // ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(); //Alternatively using this line, but not required.
                //System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)bitmap; //Working Fine, but No need of this line just verifying whether it gives error or not.
                //byte[] bt = ms.ToArray();// Working Fine, but No need of //this line just verifying whether it gives error or not.

                //pdftron.PDF.Image image = pdftron.PDF.Image.Create(doc, ms.ToArray(), 200, 200, 100, cs); // This line works fine, but we don’t need to use this.
               // pdftron.PDF.Image image = pdftron.PDF.Image.Create(doc, "E:\\SomeTestImage.jpg", JBIG2_hint); // This line also works fine, but we don’t need to use this.

                pdftron.PDF.Image image = pdftron.PDF.Image.Create(doc, bitmap, JBIG2_hint); // I need this line as its our requirement, but this line gives error  “Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow”  and need solution for this why it gives error.

                element = f.CreateImage(image, new Matrix2D(page.GetPageWidth(), 0, 0, page.GetPageHeight(), 0, 0));
                writer.WriteElement(element);
                writer.End();
                doc.PagePushBack(page);

            }
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException aex)
        {

        }
        catch (PDFNetException pex)
        {
            //Why Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow occurs and catch in this PDFNetException , and not in Arithmetic Exception, this is also my query.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return doc;
 }
```

Comment: Does this occur with any image source? Or only certain ones? Finally, what version of PDFNet are you using? You can call PDFNet.GetVersion at runtime

Comment: This happens with all Images, which we had saved in SQL Database in byte[] array format. Images are not corrupt,working fine at other places by different algorithms.But we are getting error only on this particular scenario.If there was something wrong then other overloaded Create() function of PDFNET would also not be working.The issue happens when we use "BitMap" as an argument in Create() function.Since we are using SetResolution for BitMap, hence we have to use this one only.Which line of code is working fine and which are not are explained in comments. We are using version 6.01 of PDFNet.

Comment: But earlier same version of PDFNET library works fine, but for last few months it is not working fine. And may I know are you confirm that when BitMap as an argument passed in Create() function throws error in 6.01 version of PDFNet library.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in the latest for version of PDFNet.

You can get latest official .Net builds from the following locations.

- https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFNet/

Comment: But earlier same version of PDFNET library works fine, but for last few months it is not working fine. And may I know are you confirm that when BitMap as an argument passed in Create() function throws error in 6.01 version of PDFNet library.